# Scraping nested tags in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this local second hand car dealer website. While I extracted basic information, I couldn't refine it.

Step one, extract all the bits that contain car information from page 1 to 18.

```
for page in range(1,18):
    base_url = "https://www.easycar.tw/carList.php?Action=search&show=col&lifting=desc&year=&year1=&page="+ str(page)
    response = get(base_url, headers=headers)
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    content_list = html_soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "caption"})
    print(content_list)
```

Step two, I tried to extract car price.

```
def get_basic_info(content_list):
    basic_info = []
    for item in content_list:
        basic_info.append(item.find_all(item.find_all("span", {"class" : "price"}))
    return basic_info
```

For example, if we process the HTML code below,

```
<h5><span class="price">59.8 萬</span>TOYOTA ALTIS</h5>
<h5><span class="price">32.8 萬</span>2011 SUBARU FORESTER</h5><h5>
<span class="price">108.8 萬</span>2017 LEXUS ES</h5>
```

The expected outcome will be,

```
59.8 萬
32.8 萬
108.8 萬
```

In addition, how do I extract car names from a nested tag like ones shown above.

```
TOYOTA ALTIS
2011 SUBARU FORESTER
2017 LEXUS ES
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.easycar.tw/carList.php?Action=search&show=col&lifting=desc&year=&year1=&page=1'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for h5 in soup.select('h5:has(.price)'):
    name = h5.span.find_next_sibling(text=True).strip()
    price = h5.span.text
    print(price, name)
```

Prints:

```
59.8 萬 2020 TOYOTA ALTIS
39.8 萬 2019 NISSAN LIVINA
40.8 萬 2019 TOYOTA VIOS
37.8 萬 2016 HONDA CITY
62.8 萬 2017 HONDA HR-V
52.8 萬 2018 TOYOTA YARIS
20.8 萬 2010 MITSUBISHI COLT PLUS
31.8 萬 2016 MITSUBISHI COLT PLUS
43.8 萬 2019 HYUNDAI SUPER ELANTRA
29.8 萬 2013 NISSAN LIVINA
54.8 萬 2018 LUXGEN U6 GT
25.8 萬 2011 MITSUBISHI LANCER FORTIS
52.8 萬 2016 TOYOTA CAMRY
49.8 萬 2019 TOYOTA YARIS CROSSOVER
54.8 萬 2014 MAZDA CX-5
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! This seems to be what I am looking for but it is not printing in google collab.....

Comment: @HenryLiu Try to print the soup (`print(soup)`) and make sure the data is still there (and you've not got captcha page for example).